# Can a one-fan cooler handle the temperature of an i5-8600k? (Phanteks Evolv Shift case)

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I'm going to make a build on a [Phanteks Evolv Shift](http://www.phanteks.com/Enthoo-Evolv-Shift.html) case with an i5-8600k CPU,
but I totally missed what cooling system to choose for it

In case of water cooling - there's a space only for 1-fan system, and I'm not fully sure will it handle the temperature for that CPU in such conditions

Air cooling has the same problem - Will low-profile coolers handle the temperatures?

P.s.

Not sure about the overclocking, at the moment just want to know possibilities that would handle temperatures with a standard configuration

Comment: The fan should list the CPUs it is acceptable for cooling. Otherwise there are too many factors involved for us to make a recommendation, which is what this question remains, title edit aside.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that easy - just because the cooler will mount on a particular CPU doesn't mean it'll keep the CPU cool enough for all use cases. Following the cooler mfg's minimums is like believing the minimum system requirements on software - it'll "work", but it might not be satistfactory.

Comment: http://silentpcreview.com/ will give a good general education regarding cooling.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Superuser!

We can quantify this a bit by figuring out exactly how much heat your CPU is going to output. Processors have a measurement called [TDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_design_power), or thermal design power, which indicates how much heat they are expected to output under "real world" conditions.

There's a lot of slop in TDP and it's not a hard and fast rule, but *generally speaking*, if you get a cooler that can dissipate at least the TDP of your processor, you'll be getting enough cooling to keep the CPU from thermal throttling. The slop works in because TDP assumes "average" conditions. If you're mining cryptocurrency or rendering video for instance, you'll want to go well over that number on your cooler.

[The I5-8600K has a TDP of 95 watts](https://ark.intel.com/products/126685/Intel-Core-i5-8600K-Processor-9M-Cache-up-to-4-30-GHz-), so you need a cooler capable of that *at least* that much.

The difficulty is that finding TDP info on coolers is a pain - but what you can do is look at your prospective cooler and get a feel for how it handles processors near and above the one you're going to install.

As an example, [here's a single page of a review of the Corsair H60](https://proclockers.com/reviews/cooling/corsair-hydro-series-h60-120mm-liquid-cooler-review/page/0/5) - a one 120mm fan, all-in-one, liquid CPU cooler. This review shows it holding temperatures of around 60C running at full speed when hooked up to an I7-8800K at stock clocks, which has an identical TDP of 95W. (120mm fans are large enough that they shouldn't be too loud even when running 100% all the time) - but notice that it quickly loses effectiveness as the clockrate increases.

Were this my build, I'd be comfortable running that particular cooler, since I don't overclock. If you do overclock.. find a bigger case. You're going to be a bit limited with one fan builds.

**Product recommendations are off-topic here**, but this should give you the information you need to find something that works. Start reading some cooler reviews out there and you'll get a sense quickly if they can handle your CPU. Good luck!